# Why does one of the two similar cypher command to load csv in neo4j work while the other not?

Tags: csv, neo4j, path

This works:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 10000 LOAD CSV FROM 'file:///C:\\SavedNewest\\addresses.csv' AS line
CREATE (:Address { AddId: line[0]})
```

This doesn't work:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 10000 LOAD CSV FROM 'file:///C:\\w\\workspace\\Begin\\csvs\\SavedNewest\\addresses.csv' AS line
CREATE (:Address { AddId: line[0]})
```

The error is:

```
Couldn't load the external resource at: file:/C:/Users/.../Documents/Neo4j/default.graphdb/import/w/workspace/Begin/csvs/SavedNewest/addresses.csv
```

Why does the first one work? Because the path is shorter? If yes, how short should the path be to allow the command to work?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you need: make sure that the file for import exists and its path is the same as in the query.

Second, make sure that the directory in which the file is located is included in the paths that are allowed for [import](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/reference/configuration-settings/#config_dbms.directories.import):

```
dbms.directories.import = ...
```

Read more: https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/load-csv/